# neovim adds ^M at the end of the after saving

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm new to using neovim so pardon me if the fix is too obvious.

The issue that I'm having is that if I create a file using the command.

```
nvim file.txt
```

and then edit it let's say something like this

```
hello
```

then save it with `:w`
the file will show as the following

```
hello^M
```

I tried the command `:set ff=unix`
but I does not work. I think the issue is the **init.vim** which I took from https://github.com/craftzdog/dotfiles-public

and modify it to not use fish as a terminal, the code is the following.

```
" Fundamentals "{{{
" ---------------------------------------------------------------------

" init autocmd
autocmd!
" set script encoding
scriptencoding utf-8
" stop loading config if it's on tiny or small
if !1 | finish | endif

set nocompatible
set number
syntax enable
set fileencodings=utf-8,sjis,euc-jp,latin
set encoding=utf-8
set title
set autoindent
set background=dark
set nobackup
set hlsearch
set showcmd
set cmdheight=1
set laststatus=2
set scrolloff=10
set expandtab
"let loaded_matchparen = 1
set shell=powershell.exe
set backupskip=/tmp/*,/private/tmp/*

" incremental substitution (neovim)
if has('nvim')
  set inccommand=split
endif

" Suppress appending <PasteStart> and <PasteEnd> when pasting
set t_BE=

set nosc noru nosm
" Don't redraw while executing macros (good performance config)
set lazyredraw
"set showmatch
" How many tenths of a second to blink when matching brackets
"set mat=2
" Ignore case when searching
set ignorecase
" Be smart when using tabs ;)
set smarttab
" indents
filetype plugin indent on
set shiftwidth=2
set tabstop=2
set ai "Auto indent
set si "Smart indent
set nowrap "No Wrap lines
set backspace=start,eol,indent
" Finding files - Search down into subfolders
set path+=**
set wildignore+=*/node_modules/*

" Turn off paste mode when leaving insert
autocmd InsertLeave * set nopaste

" Add asterisks in block comments
set formatoptions+=r

"}}}

" Highlights "{{{
" ---------------------------------------------------------------------
set cursorline
"set cursorcolumn

" Set cursor line color on visual mode
highlight Visual cterm=NONE ctermbg=236 ctermfg=NONE guibg=Grey40

highlight LineNr cterm=none ctermfg=240 guifg=#2b506e guibg=#000000

augroup BgHighlight
  autocmd!
  autocmd WinEnter * set cul
  autocmd WinLeave * set nocul
augroup END

if &term =~ "screen"
  autocmd BufEnter * if bufname("") !~ "^?[A-Za-z0-9?]*://" | silent! exe '!echo -n "\ek[`hostname`:`basename $PWD`/`basename %`]\e\\"' | endif
  autocmd VimLeave * silent!  exe '!echo -n "\ek[`hostname`:`basename $PWD`]\e\\"'
endif

"}}}

" File types "{{{
" ---------------------------------------------------------------------
" JavaScript
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.es6 setf javascript
" TypeScript
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.tsx setf typescriptreact
" Markdown
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.md set filetype=markdown
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.mdx set filetype=markdown
" Flow
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.flow set filetype=javascript
" powershell
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.pwsh set filetype=powershell

set suffixesadd=.js,.es,.jsx,.json,.css,.less,.sass,.styl,.php,.py,.md

autocmd FileType coffee setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2
autocmd FileType ruby setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2
autocmd FileType yaml setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2

"}}}

" Imports "{{{
" ---------------------------------------------------------------------
runtime ./plug.vim
if has("unix")
  let s:uname = system("uname -s")
  " Do Mac stuff
  if s:uname == "Darwin\n"
    runtime ./macos.vim
  endif
endif
if has('win32')
  runtime ./windows.vim
endif

runtime ./maps.vim
"}}}

" Syntax theme "{{{
" ---------------------------------------------------------------------

" true color
if exists("&termguicolors") && exists("&winblend")
  syntax enable
  set termguicolors
  set winblend=0
  set wildoptions=pum
  set pumblend=5
  set background=dark
  " Use NeoSolarized
  let g:neosolarized_termtrans=1
  runtime ./colors/NeoSolarized.vim
  colorscheme NeoSolarized
endif

"}}}

" Extras "{{{
" ---------------------------------------------------------------------
set exrc
"}}}

" vim: set foldmethod=marker foldlevel=0:
```

any help would be so much appreciated

**Quick note** It appears that the issue only happens when is a **.tsx** file

Answer (score -1):

I finally found the culprit. It was prettier, I remove it from the lspconfig.rc file as a temporary solution please let me know if you why this was happening